If $p$ is an equilibrium point of $f$ , then either $\varphi(t)\neq p$ for all $t$ or $\varphi(t)=p$ for all $t$
Let $p$ be an equilibrium point of a $C^1$ vector field $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (that is, $f(p) = 0$). Let $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a solution of the equation $\dot{x} = f(x)$ such that
$$
p \in \overline{\operatorname{Im} \varphi}.
$$
Prove that either $\operatorname{Im} \varphi = p$ or $p \notin \operatorname{Im} \varphi$.
I started by assuming that $p \in \operatorname{Im} \varphi$ (else I am done) so there exist $t_1$ such that $\varphi($$t_1$)=$p$. this point is an equilibrium point and since we can apply Picard uniqueness Theorem (f is $C^1$) and since $\varPsi(t)=p$ is infact a solution and $\varPsi($$t_1$$)=p$ we have a solution on the same IVP thus our solutions in fact the same and $\varphi(t)=p$ for all t thus $\operatorname{Im} \varphi = p$.
I am not sure if my solution is correct since I basically said the "for all t" but Picard is for (a,b) and I also haven't even used the fact that p is in the closure.
I would appreciate some guidance and Thanks in advance.

Consider some examples like $\dot y=1-y^2$, $y(0)=0$, to find that the second case is also valid.

Not following, where do I use the fact that p is in the closure?

Rephrase the question as follows: If $p$ is an equilibrium point of $f$, then either $\varphi(t)\ne p$ for all $t$ or $\varphi(t)=p$ for all $t$.
